# Javascript: Object function causing problems

Tags: javascript

I have tag trigger working by setInterval and it alerts when it find the tag in the document. the code did not have any problem until I've got the function into an object for arrangement,

Live examples:

1. here is an working example without object : http://jsfiddle.net/ae6Xc/4/
2. here is example with object (with the problem) : http://jsfiddle.net/ae6Xc/10/

here is the "original" working code without the object:

```
// looking for the special tag than save the
// element in varabile and than alert
(function(){
var win = window ,
    doc = document ,

    setInter = 'setInterval' ,
    clearInter = 'clearInterval' ,

    getByTagName = 'getElementsByTagName' ,

    KW_pluslike = 'mysite:plugin' ,

    zero = 0  ,

    element;

    // Set 'setInterval' function as trigger
    //    to target the Special tag.
var trigger = win[setInter](function(){

    // Check if such tag exist , if not repeat. When the tag
    // has founded , it set the root to the Element var.
    if(doc[getByTagName](KW_pluslike)[zero]){
        element = doc[getByTagName](KW_pluslike)[zero];
        win[clearInter](trigger);
        alert("Tag Captured");
    }
} , 1000 /5 );

})();
```

so as i said , i wanted to arrange the things up a little so i took the Trigger function and the Element variable and replaced them into an object like this :

```
var pluslike = {

    element : nul ,
    trigger : win[setInter](function(){
        if(doc[getByTagName](KW_pluslike)[zero]){
            pluslike.element = doc[getByTagName](KW_pluslike)[zero];
            win[clearInter](pluslike.trigger);
            alert("Tag Captured");
        }
    } ,  1000 /5 );
}
pluslike.trigger;
```

somehow for some reason it's not working , what causes the problem? i don't know. when it started? when i used the function in object.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Why in the world are you using that syntax for calling functions?

Comment: @Dark Falcon: Probably so it can be minified more agressively. (It is unnecesarily complicated for StackOverflow, however); still, var zero seems completely pointless

Comment: ...and -1 for not being more explicit about "not working"

Comment: @missingno what do you want me to tell you? the code work. i took it into object and than it not worked , the problem what when i inserted the code into object , what can i be more specific here?

Comment: how about saying what error message you got? You said what change you made but didn't say what the problem was in the end. The best questions don't need anyone to run the code in order to be answered.

Comment: Fix these things first: http://www.jshint.com/reports/48008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semicolon inside the object literal is causing your problem. **Fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/ae6Xc/11/**
Inside an object literal, properties should be separated by commas. Semicolons are not allowed

Comparison of your code, and the patched code:

```
    trigger : win[setInter](... ,  1000 /5 ); //<---Semicolon!!!@!@!@
    trigger : win[setInter](... , 1000 /5 )   //<-- Patched, no semicolon
```

Comment: can you reread the post? in example 2 i gave you the code i replaced , it's currently inside the anonymous function. look in live example in the first lines of the post.

Comment: @MorSela Updated answer. I have to admit that I didn't look at your links at the first time, because you had already posted partial code in your answer.

Comment: thank you so much it really helped. if i may i have an other question, in the code with the object , how can it automatically run the "trigger" function without calling it separately ?

Comment: @MorSela You don't have to call `pluslike.trigger`. You will even get an error when you use `pluslike.trigger()`, becayse `pluslike.trigger` is not a function, but the reference to the created interval.